# This while loop is hitting both outputs instead of just the one I expected

Tags: c++

So I've built a dictionary in a Binary Search Tree where the user should be able to look up a word in the program which will be retrieved from a .txt file and displayed with its definition.

I'm using a keyword function to search the first word of each line, when the right word is found the function gets the whole line and displays it.

Here's the issue, if I search for a word not in the dictionary the function outputs "word not found" like I would expect.  However, anytime I search a word that is in the file I get both the word/def output AND the "word not found" message that I only want to appear if there was no match.

Here is where the keyword function is called:

```
case 1:
            cout << "\nEnter the word that you would like to look up:" << endl;
            cin >> word;
            wordFile.open("dictionaryWords.txt");
            B.Keyword(wordFile , word);
            wordFile.close();

            cout << endl;

            break;
```

and here is the keyword function with the while loop in question.

```
void BSTree::Keyword(fstream & wordFile, string word) {
    string def;
    while (getline(wordFile, def)) {
        if (def.find(word) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << def << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << word << " not found" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to break out of your while loop.

Comment: More like`return` in the if, after `cout`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `cout << word << " not found" << endl;` isn't part of a condition so it will always print.  You need to add logic to stop that.

Comment: Thank you all! I made it a bool instead of void and added 'return' in the 'if' statement when found and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't 'exit' the loop once you found the word and printed it out. you should add break; after your cout << def << endl; Also you should put a Boolean that tells you if you found the word like this :

```
void BSTree::Keyword(fstream & wordFile, string word) {
string def;
bool found = false;
while (getline(wordFile, def)) {
    if (def.find(word) != string::npos)
    {
        cout << def << endl;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found){
    cout << word << " not found" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `break` is not going to stop `not found` from printing.

Comment: You can save all of that work by replacing `break` with `return`.

Comment: Yea I guess that's an easier way

Comment: I made the whole function a `bool` and then used a `return` to get out f the loop when found, thank you both for your help.

Comment: No problem ! Glad I could help

Comment: If that's all you needed please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an infinite loop for me. You need to add break in while loop if word is found.